# How to save a scikit-learn classifier that utilizes a vectorizer, a pipeline and GridSearchV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, text-classification

I built a sentiment classifier using the following steps:

```
load dataset with pandas

count = CountVectorizer()
bag = count.fit_transform(x)
bag.toarray()
tfidf = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True, norm="l2",smooth_idf=True)
tfidf.fit_transform(bag).toarray()

from collections import Counter

vocab = Counter()
for text in x:
    for word in text.split(" "):
        vocab[word] += 1

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')

vocab_reduced = Counter()
for w, c in vocab.items():
    if not w in stop:
        vocab_reduced[w]=c

def preprocessor(text):
    """ Return a cleaned version of text
    """
    # Remove HTML markup
    text = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', text)
    # Save emoticons for later appending
    emoticons = re.findall('(?::|;|=)(?:-)?(?:\)|\(|D|P)', text)
    # Remove any non-word character and append the emoticons,
    # removing the nose character for standarization. Convert to lower case
    text = (re.sub('[\W]+', ' ', text.lower()) + ' ' + ' '.join(emoticons).replace('-', ''))
    
    return text

from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

porter = PorterStemmer()

def tokenizer(text):
    return text.split()

def tokenizer_porter(text):
    return [porter.stem(word) for word in text.split()]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents=None,
                        lowercase=False,
                        preprocessor=None)

param_grid = [{'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1)],
               'vect__stop_words': [stop, None],
               'vect__tokenizer': [tokenizer, tokenizer_porter],
               'vect__preprocessor': [None, preprocessor],
               'vect__use_idf':[False],
               'vect__norm':[None],
               "clf__alpha":[0,1],
               "clf__fit_prior":[False,True]},
                ]
multi_tfidf = Pipeline([("vect", tfidf),
                       ( "clf", MultinomialNB())])
gs_multi_tfidf = GridSearchCV(multi_tfidf, param_grid,
                              scoring="accuracy",
                              cv=5,
                              verbose=1,
                              n_jobs=-1)
gs_multi_tfidf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I tried saving the pipeline with joblib and saving both, the classifier as well as the pipeline to then use it for a website. But everytime I tried, it didn't work. I either got: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` (when having saved both the pipeline and the classifier) or `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` when just using the classifier.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following. Any specific reason why you do not include CountVectorizer() and TfidfTransformer() ? You should also exactly specify how you attempted to save the model.

```
multi_tfidf = Pipeline([("vect", TfidfVectorizer()),
                       ( "clf", MultinomialNB())])
```

Comment: I used this tutorial: https://github.com/Abhishek-MLDL/logistic-sentiment/blob/master/Sentiment%20analysis%20with%20Logistic%20Regression.ipynb and he didn't do it like you said I should either.

On how I saved it:
joblib.dump(Pipeline, "Finished Models/MultinominalNB/MultinominalNB_pipeline.joblib") and joblib.dump(gs_multi_tfidf.best_estimator_, "Finished Models/MultinominalNB/MultinominalNB_Grid.joblib")

Do you think I should preprocess my data beforehand and then use tfidftransformer? Then use GridsearchV without a pipeline?